# Why doesn't sudo know where psql is?

Tags: centos, postgresql, sudo

#### The problem

The [CKAN installation documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/install-from-source.html) shows you how to list the installed PostgreSQL databases.

The command looks like this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -l
```

When I try that in my shell, I get an error:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -l
sudo: psql: command not found
```

#### The workaround

Daniel2d2art on the [CentOS forum](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=39962) worked around the problem by fully qualifying the path to psql.

My psql lives in the directory `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin`, so my workaround now looks like this:

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/psql -l
```

When I try that in my shell, it works:

```
$ sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/psql -l
                                   List of databases
     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgis_test | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

#### How do I fix it properly?

I shouldn't have to fully qualify the path, right?

The postgres user already has psql in its path:

```
$ sudo -u postgres echo $PATH
/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

How do I fix this properly?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/257666/2213874 or this http://superuser.com/a/232258/213081 ... otherwise maybe a symlink of pgsql to /bin

Comment: You should be able to use `sudo -E -u postgres psql -l` as long as your $PATH has `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/` in it.

Comment: @krowe `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin` (no trailing slash) is in my path, but `sudo -E -u postgres psql -l` produces the same error: `sudo: psql: command not found`.

Comment: @DrewKhoury Awesome. Your second link had the answer. I used it to write my [own answer](http://serverfault.com/a/541880/53319). Thanks!

Comment: Just for fun do you mind trying: `sudo -E -U postgres psql -l` ? I think I had a mistake in my original answer.

Comment: @krowe `sudo: the \`-U' option may only be used with the \`-l' option`. From `man sudo`: "The -U (other user) option is used in conjunction with the -l option to specify the user whose privileges should be listed.  The security policy may restrict listing other users’ privileges.  The sudoers policy only allows root or a user with the ALL privilege on the current host to use this option."

Comment: @krowe I think you did mean `-u`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work here. From `man sudo`: "The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified command as a user other than root.  [...]  Security policies may restrict uids to those listed in the password database.  The sudoers policy allows uids that are not in the password database as long as the targetpw option is not set.  Other security policies may not support this."

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'd bet the -E option would've made it work though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why sudo ignores your path

sudo doesn't use your user's path or the postgres user's path. sudo has its own path, defined by the the `secure_path` variable in the file `/etc/sudoers`.

The output of `echo $PATH` is misleading in this case. To see the path that sudo really uses, use `printenv PATH` instead. In my case, the output looked like this:

```
$ sudo -u postgres printenv PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

The output doesn't contain `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin`, where psql lives, so it's not in sudo's path either.

To fix the problem you can add where psql lives to the `secure_path` variable.

#### How to tell sudo where psql lives

Use `sudo visudo` to open `/etc/sudoers` in vi.

The file should contain a line like this:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

This line sets the path for sudo. The part after the equals sign is the same as the output of the previous `printenv PATH` example.

Replace it with something like this:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin
```

The replacement appends `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin` to the path list. The path list separator is a colon (`:`).

Save and close the file.

To check that it worked, try the `printenv PATH` command again:

```
$ sudo -u postgres printenv PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin
```

Looks good!

Now try the `psql -l` command:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -l
                                   List of databases
     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgis_test | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

It works!

Thanks to [Drew Khoury](https://serverfault.com/questions/541847/why-doesnt-sudo-know-where-psql-is#comment623841_541847) who pointed me to a solution for a similar problem on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables/232258#232258).

Comment: BTW, the command: `sudo -l -U postgres` is a better way to see the sudo environment for a user. Be sure to use a big U.

Comment: @krowe Here that produces the message: `User postgres is not allowed to run sudo on <hostname>.`.

Comment: That could be gotten rid of if you setup postgres as a sudo user. But that isn't really any easier than your solution as it is.

Answer (score 0):

a small workaround - if you have no problem with executing more commands, you can switch user

```
sudo su postgres
```

and then

```
psql -l
```

should work.

Comment: This works, but I need a one-liner. As a one-liner this becomes `sudo su postgres --command="psql -l"`, which works, but doesn't solve the fundamental problem. Thanks for the tip all the same!